# Debugging a code takes me to stdio.h lib

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have a C program which starts with `#include <stdio.h>`.

When I debug a `printf` statement, the debugger takes me to the `studio.h` library, which shows me step by step how the `printf` function is done. Obviously I don't want this to happen because it takes too long.
It does print the text I wanted to print.

Any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: I think there is the stack frame somewhere in the tool bar at the top where you can look and select your function that call stdlib.

Comment: The title don't really match the question. The title should be a short summary of the problem described in the question body. Please [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As for the problem in the question body, there are two ways to step through your code: Step *into* function calls, and step *over* function calls. Unless you want to debug `printf` (or other standard and system functions) you should step *over* those calls.

Comment: It is an indication that your `printf` call is not correct.

Comment: ***Or*** do you mean that the program execution *stops* in the `printf` function when you just *run* in the debugger? Then you probably have a crash, and you should go up the function call stack until you come to your code, and examine what you're doing there.

Comment: Set a break point after the `printf`, then continue. If the debugger still stops inside `printf`, it likely means you passed invalid arguments to the function.

Comment: it seems your using the `step into` function of the debugger.  When you want to NOT step into a function, like `printf()`, then when the code execution gets to the line calling `printf()`, use the `step over` function of the debugger.

Comment: It's still unclear what you do. ***How*** do "the debugger take [you] to the stdio.h-library"? What do ***you*** do to end up there?

Answer (score 1):

When debugging you are probably using the "**Step Into**"(F11) action in the debugger which will take you to the next line of code inside that function. If you don't want to see the code execution inside the function you should use "**Step Over**"(F10).

Use "**Step Into**" when you want to see the execution of the code **INSIDE** the function.

Use "**Step Over**" for faster and more scoped out debugging.